# A symbol in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, symbols, arrows

I want to write this symbol in LaTeX.

[image]

I looked for it on Detexify and some code-lists but found nothing.

EDIT: I want the arrows and also the letters (general inputs in that place)

Thanks!

Comment: just the arrows, or the letters above/below as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another solution with [tikz-cd](/questions/tagged/tikz-cd):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[shift left=2pt]{r}{e} & B\arrow[shift left=2pt]{l}{c}
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

And yet another one with `unicode-math` and `substack`:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\newcommand*{\myarrows}[2]{\mathrel{\substack{#1\\\displaystyle\rightleftarrows\\#2}}}

\begin{document}
\[
A \myarrows{e}{c} B 
\]
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\[
A \myarrows{e}{c} B 
\]
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}
\[
A \myarrows{e}{c} B 
\]
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
\[
A \myarrows{e}{c} B 
\]
%\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math} currently not installed on my system
%\[
%A \myarrows{e}{c} B 
%\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I have found five possible ways to do this, out of which 2 match your requirements; however, the arrows are not extensible in those! Further information can be found in the code itself.

Note: No matter which method you choose the alignment just isn't right in all of them!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{chemarrow}

\hbadness=10000  %For Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) warning.

%%%%%%% Taken from Math mode – v. 2.47 %%%%%%% 

% Method 1:
\makeatletter
\newcommand\zleftrightarrow[2][]{\ext@arrow 0099{\longleftrightarrowfill@}{#1}{#2}}
\def\longleftrightarrowfill@{\arrowfill@\leftarrow\relbar\rightarrow}
\makeatother

% Method 2:
\makeatletter
\def\rightharpoondownfill@{%
\arrowfill@\relbar\relbar\rightharpoondown}
\def\rightharpoonupfill@{%
\arrowfill@\relbar\relbar\rightharpoonup}
\def\leftharpoondownfill@{%
\arrowfill@\leftharpoondown\relbar\relbar}
\def\leftharpoonupfill@{%
\arrowfill@\leftharpoonup\relbar\relbar}
\newcommand{\xrightharpoondown}[2][]{%
\ext@arrow 0099\rightharpoondownfill@{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\xrightharpoonup}[2][]{%
\ext@arrow 0099\rightharpoonupfill@{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\xleftharpoondown}[2][]{%
\ext@arrow 0099\leftharpoondownfill@{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\xleftharpoonup}[2][]{%
\ext@arrow 0099\leftharpoonupfill@{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\xleftrightharpoons}[2][]{\mathrel{%
\raise.22ex\hbox{%
$\ext@arrow 0099\leftharpoonupfill@{\phantom{#1}}{#2}$}%
\setbox0=\hbox{%
$\ext@arrow 0099\rightharpoondownfill@{#1}{\phantom{#2}}$}%
\kern-\wd0 \lower.22ex\box0}%
}
\newcommand{\xrightleftharpoons}[2][]{\mathrel{%
\raise.22ex\hbox{%
$\ext@arrow 0099\rightharpoonupfill@{\phantom{#1}}{#2}$}%
\setbox0=\hbox{%
$\ext@arrow 0099\leftharpoondownfill@{#1}{\phantom{#2}}$}%
\kern-\wd0 \lower.22ex\box0}%
}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\Huge
\show\rightarrow
\show\leftarrow
\show\leftrightarrows

\hspace*{\fill}$\autorightleftharpoons{3}{f}$\hspace*{\fill}\\[30pt] % chemarrow package

\hspace*{\fill}$A \overset{F}{\underset{G}\rightleftarrows} X$\hspace*{\fill}\\[30pt]

\hspace*{\fill}$a\zleftrightarrow[under]{over}b$\hspace*{\fill}\\[30pt] % Method 1

\hspace*{\fill}$a\xleftrightharpoons[down]{up}b$\hspace*{\fill}\\[5pt] % Method 2

\hspace*{\fill}\[a \mathrel{\mathop{\rightleftarrows}^{\mathrm{over}}_{\mathrm{under}}} b\]\hspace*{\fill}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the best solution (spacing seems off to me), but you can turn `\leftrightarrows` into a math operator and turn on limits:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand\weird{\mathop\leftrightarrows\limits}

\begin{document}
$\weird^3_f$
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: I think what you need is the `\autoleftrightharpoons{<text above>}{<text below>}` command from the `chemarrow` package. See Table 169 on page 60 of "The Comprehensive LATEX Symbol List" (source: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/?lang=en).

Comment: @Amar It's still not an exact match, but you should consider posting that as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the arrows to show a chemical reaction?

Then you might be interested in knowing that you can use the `mhchem` package which simplifies writing reactions. It gives the same result as Amar's code but you don't have to include all the extra definitions yourself.

I used the option `arrows=pgf` to get arrow heads more like the ones in your picture.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[arrows=pgf]{mhchem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\ce{H2 + 1/2O2 <-->[a][b] H2O}
\end{document}
```

And the result:
[image: mhchemisnice]

Comment: I'm not using it for chemical reactions hahaha, I'm using it for a correspondence between two sets.  Thanks anyway =)

Answer (score 1):

There is another package for this task not yet mentioned: `stackrel`. It adds an optional argument to the LaTeX `\stackrel` command to set something below the relation, as in

```
\usepackage{stackrel}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\[  \stackrel[c]{e}{\leftrightarrows}  \]
```

[image]

Comment: I'm glad the stackengine made it on here in some way, but see tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/17423.

Comment: Then use `\[`/`\]` :)